# R data.table segfault when trying to update one column and create another

Tags: r, data.table

Is it possible to create a new column in a data.table and update an existing column at the same time?  The following didn't work.  Thanks.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(x=runif(4), y=runif(4), z=c("x","x","y","y"))
dt[, c("x", "y") := list(x[1], y[1]), by=z]     # works
dt[, c("x", "newx") := list(x[1], y[1]), by=z]
```

Caught Segfault:

```
address 0x20000010, cause 'memory not mapped'
```

Traceback:

```
 1: [.data.table(dt, , :=(c("x", "newx"), list(x[1], y[1])), by = z)
 2: dt[, :=(c("x", "newx"), list(x[1], y[1])), by = z]
```

Comment: Ouch, yeah, I've done that before, too. I think I just avoided doing it instead of filing it as a bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. But you need v1.8.9 from R-Forge to get the following fix :

> o  Mixing adding and updating into one DT[, `:=`(existingCol=...,newCol=...), by=...] now works
>        without error or segfault, #2778 and #2528. Many thanks to Arunkumar Srinivasan for reporting
>        and for the nice reproducible examples. Tests added.

See [latest NEWS](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/NEWS?view=markup&root=datatable) (updated live) for other changes in v1.8.9.

Comment: Where does one find the .tar.gz file for v1.8.9?

Comment: @DWin It's on R-Forge, here: `R-Forge.R-project.org/src/contrib/data.table_1.8.9.tar.gz`. You can install it directly with something like: `install.packages("data.table", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org", type="source")`.

Comment: Thanks. Believe me, I _do_ know how to install from source. And I generally am able to find packages, but the current setup of R-Forge seems to be frustrating my usual searching strategies. Is there a standard location for the packed devel-version of packages in R-Forge?

Comment: @DWin I believe https://r-forge.r-project.org/projects/<projectname> in our case https://r-forge.r-project.org/projects/datatable (no dot) and then click the "R Packages" link in the top right. But the [data.table homepage](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/) has all the links a user should need including a .zip for Windows I upload since no binary is available when R-Forge is in "Building" state (which can be a long time sometimes!)